# Remove h1 class="page-title" from ENFOLD theme

Tags: wordpress, seo, themes

I am trying to optimize a site for SEO, using WordPress and the Enfold theme.

The theme is generating an extra `<h1>` tag with the class of page-title

For example:

```
<h1 class="page-title"> </h1>
```

I have looked in every theme file imaginable and can't find the culprit anywhere.

The site is fivestarmusic.com.au

Comment: I have checked your website source, but it's only one "page-title" in the source not two or more? where is the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi Majid,
The h1 page-tile is showing up on all category pages, not the home page (for example if you click on guitars or drums etc) you'll notice a h1 with display:none, just above the h1 that i've placed there,
Thanks for having a look, i am completely stuck!

Comment: if it's on Category page then I would be on your woocomerce template under your theme folder, it's hard to say you just have to investigate within your theme,

Comment: Majid you legend!
I didn;t even think to check the woocommerce files, first one i chose, there it was. 
Thank you very much man, my gratitude is stronger than a thousand oceans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, that header is under your WooCommerce template, possibly under your theme folder. You need to look for that here:

```
wp-content
   |--- Themes
      |--- yourTheme
         |--- Woocomerce
```

It should be under this folder, name Category.php or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Modify function-enfold.php, and look for this code:

```
// Disable title if requested
if($header_settings['header_title_bar'] == 'breadcrumbs_only')
    $args['title'] = '';
```

Replace it with:

```
// Disable title if requested
if($header_settings['header_title_bar'] == 'breadcrumbs_only')
    $args['html'] = "<div class='{class} title_container'><div class='container'>{additions}</div></div>";
```